# Displaying a new image/window when rollover an image using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

When I first asked how to achieve something like this: http://backpack.tf/ I got pointed to JQuery.

I managed to create a new small window when I hover over images using this; http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

But I can't figure out how to construct it so that it can show detailed information about some PHP object like in `backpack.tf`

Is JQuery the correct way?

Comment: you can use [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers), it use jquery and the popovers accept as trigger option `hover`

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery Power Tip

http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/

you just need to put your html in element title attribute.